# how to display different lists by a dynamic tab system?

Tags: html, list, listview, angular7

I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```
[{
  "name": "Equipment",
  "functional_id": "furniture",
  "products": [
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "White bags",
      "description": "Reusable",
      "id": 11,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Small model",
          "description": "25",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "white_bags_small_model_by_25"
        },
        {
          "name": "Medium model",
          "description": "20",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "white_bags_medium_model_by_20"
        },
        {
          "name": "Large model",
          "description": "10",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "white_bags_large_model_by_10"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Burgundy bags",
      "description": "Reusable",
      "id": 12,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Small model",
          "description": "25",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "bags_burgundy_bags_small_model_by_10"
        },
        {
          "name": "Large model",
          "description": "Par 10",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "bags_burgundy_bags_large_model_by_10"
        }
      ]
    }    
  ],
  "sorting": 2300"
},
{
  "name": "Documents",
  "functional_id": "docs",
  "products": [
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Book of conventions",
      "id": 17,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "agreement_book"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Procedure posters",
      "description": "Procedure",
      "id": 18,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "posters_procedure_of_taking_in_charge"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Services Brochures",
      "description": "Brochures",
      "id": 19,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "services_brochures"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Catalogue",
      "id": 20,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "catalogue"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sorting": 2400
},
{
  "name": "Products",
  "functional_id": "prods",
  "products": [
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Articles",
      "id": 19,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "book_1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Procedure_b",
      "description": "Procedure",
      "id": 24,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "book_charge"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Book Services",
      "description": "Book Services",
      "id": 26,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "book_services"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Catalogue",
      "id": 32,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "catalogue"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sorting": 4400
}
]
```

and I represent it in my application with the following html:

```
  <div class='col-lg-12' *ngIf="this.market && this.market.length>0 ">
    <ng-container *ngFor='let category of this.market | orderBy:"sorting"'>
      <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
      <table class='table table-bordered bg-white'>
        <thead class='bg-quinary  d-xl-table-row  d-none'>
        <th>Produits</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Prix HT</th>
        <th>Quantités</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let product of category.products | orderBy:"id"' class="  ">
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div *ngIf="product && product.path " style="width: 150px">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{product.file}}" alt="" width="150px">
              </div>
              <div style="flex: 5" class="p-2">
                <h2 class="p-1">{{product.name}}</h2>
                <p [innerHTML]="product.description" class="text-muted" *ngIf=" product && product.description"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="p-0 d-xl-table-cell d-none">
            <ul class="p-0 m-0">
              <li *ngFor='let item of product.items'>
                <div style="line-height: 24px" class="">
                  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                  <p class="text-muted">{{item.description}}</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="p-0 d-xl-table-cell d-none">
            <ul class="p-0 m-0">
              <li *ngFor='let item of product.items'>
                <span>{{item.price || '-'}} €</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="p-0 d-xl-table-cell d-none">
            <ul class="p-0 m-0">
              <li *ngFor='let item of product.items'>
                <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="item.quantity" (change)="this.updateCart(item)" style="height: 45px; line-height: 45px" min="0">
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="p-0 d-table-cell d-xl-none w-100">
            <ul class="font">
              <li *ngFor='let item of product.items' class=" p-3 item">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column w-25  align-self-center">
                  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                  <p class="text-muted">{{item.description}}</p>
                </div>
                <span class="d-flex flex-column  w-25 align-self-center">{{item.price || '-'}} €</span>
                <input  class="d-flex flex-column  w-25 align-self-center" type="number" [(ngModel)]="item.quantity" (change)="this.updateCart(item, product.id)" style="height: 45px" min="0"   >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Since the list of the different types of products is very wide (I have simplified the array of objects), a very large scroll is generated. 
I am trying to create, following the same list style, a system of tabs through which to load the different types of products according to the tab you select. 
To do this I am trying to use the following bootstrap component

```
<div class='col-lg-12' *ngIf="this.market && this.market.length>0 ">
    <nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" style="background-color: #0e5fa4;" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true"><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; color: white; padding: 0;">Equipment</p></a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" style="background-color: white; border: 0.5px solid #0e5fa4;" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Documents</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" style="background-color: white; border: 0.5px solid #0e5fa4;" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Products</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In this way, the only thing I have managed to do is to show the different types of products in the different tabs in a static way, but I cannot make the dynamic navigation between them.
If someone sees what I'm doing wrong.
A greeting and thank you in advance

Comment: So you're aware, there are errors in the JSON you've posted in the question. According to https://jsonlint.com it starts on line 51

Comment: @MattSaunders I tried to simplify it for the example, I may have made a mistake in simplifying it, sorry

Comment: Ah no problem - just wanted to check it wasn't causing you any headaches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a barebones implementation of dynamic tabs in Angular, with a list of items in each tab. Demo up on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5uupgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).

**Template**:

```
<!-- Tab Buttons -->

<ul class="tabs">
    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index">
        <button (click)="selectedTab = i" [ngStyle]="selectedTab === i && {'background':'blue', 'color':'white'}">{{tab.label}}</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab Content -->

<div>
    <h3>{{tabs[selectedTab].label}}</h3>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of tabs[selectedTab].items">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Component**:

```
  tabs = [
    {
      label: 'Products',
      items: ['Ball', 'Car', 'Bricks']
    },
    {
      label: 'People',
      items: ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chris']
    }, {
      label: 'Animals',
      items: ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse']
    }
  ];
  selectedTab = 0;
```

`tabs` in the component represents an array of the objects you want to present with tabs. This is far simpler than the data structure you've posted, but the principles are the same.